# hard disk not recognized

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, hard-drive, partitioning, formatting

I have red-hat enterprise 6.2 and I have just bought a new hard disk for 1.7 TB. My OS doesn't seem  to see that disk. I was expecting  to see `/dev/sdb` or some new entry returned by `lsblck` but nothing shows up.

What this symptom could mean?

Dummy question: what's are the basic steps in this case you normally do?

Do I have to manually do the following

1. create a new partition
2. format the disk
3. attach the disk
4. mount the disk

Comment: Open - enterprise setups are allowed on serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See whether it shows up in BIOS.

If it doesn't, then return to dealer. Getting a defective piece of equipment happens, even new equipment - it is not like the distributor tests it before sending, and even if they did it can get a rough transport. Thus, it's DOA - Dead On Arrival. Return it and get a replacement.

Comment: You were right. We found that the hard disk was not active in the bios. This is the reason we couldn't see it at all in the OS. Thanks a lot.